# Additional validation message displayed on mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, validationmessage

I have a simple mvc web app, that is searching transactions in the DB using a specified search parameter(named RA number), now I decided to add jquery block ui on my app and I then realized the block fires even when an empty string("" single or double space bar in textbox) is entered.

I have data annotation in my RA view model, I then added an AllowEmptryStrings = false attribute on my view model property, see code below

```
public class SearchByRAViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an RA number",AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string RANumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my action method from my controller code

```
public ActionResult SearchTollTransactions(SearchByRAViewModel raViewModel)
{
    List<TollScrapingTransactionScreen> tollScrapingList = new List<TollScrapingTransactionScreen>();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        tollScrapingList = GetTransactionByRA(raViewModel.RANumber);
        ViewBag.RANumber = raViewModel.RANumber;
        return View(tollScrapingList);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

My only problem now is, there seems to be an extra validation message displayed on the search page(index) if there is an empty string in the search text box, see screenshot

[image: double validation message]

Here is my block ui section, in case someone wonders where it is

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    // there should be at least a value for ra before firing the blockui
    var raValue = $('#raNumber').val();
    if (!raValue || raValue.trim() === '') {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $.blockUI();
    }
});
```

This is the part of my view, which is inside the normal @using(Html.BegingForm)

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Search by RA number</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <table class="table form-table">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-sm-2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RANumber)</th>
                            <td class="col-sm-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RANumber, new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = 1, @id = "raNumber" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RANumber)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-toolbar col-sm-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search Transaction" class="btn pull-right" tabindex="2" id="btnSearch" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: The default for `AllowEmptyStrings` is already `false` - you do not need to add that attribute

Comment: Well before posting this question, I tried removing the attribute but still got the same issue, the error message still displayed twice

Comment: You have not shown your view

Comment: Apologies, I forgot about it, I have now edited my question and the code has been included in the last part of the question, thank for heads up

Comment: And do you also have `@Html.ValidationSummary()`?

Comment: No, I thought that was the reason why the error message displays at the top as well, so I deleted that line

Comment: I have found the problem, I have a navigation bar partial layout which had a @Html.ValidationSummary(), this is the reason why  the message appeared twice, it has been removed and all is well now